# Storing data within a map of a vector of structs of a vector of structs

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, struct

First post here, and I'm working on some code to try to read from multiples CSV files, combine them into a "Master" CSV file. (CODING in: C++ Visual Studio 2013 by the way)

Anyways, that's not the trouble I'm having. I'm having difficulty with setting up my initial container I would like to store these values into. Here's my set-up so far:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
    struct GradeCategories{
        string category;
        int grade;
    }; GradeCategories grade_cat;

    struct NameGrades{
        string name;
        vector<GradeCategories> v;
    }; NameGrades NG;

    typedef map<int, vector<NameGrades>> TheBook;
```

So how would I go about even accessing/inputting data into this set up?

I attempted:

`TheBook[12345017][NG.name = "Bob Jones"].push_back((grade_cat.category = "Exam 1")(grade_cat.grade = 95));`

Other than that, I don't really see how I would access the internal components of this. Extremely new to maps, and this deep of an "inception" of code is kind of throwing me.

So any help with that would be very appreciated! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `TheBook`, maps `int` onto a `vector` of `NameGrades`, which means:

```
TheBook[int] = vector<NameGrades>;
```

Start with one `GradeCatagories` object: `grade_cat`

```
grade_cat.category = "Exam";
grade_cat.grade = 95;
```

Now place it in a `vector`:

```
vector<GradeCategories> vgc;
vgc.push_back(grade_cat);
```

Now we can move on to `NG`:

```
NG.name = "Bob Jones";
NG.v = vgc;
```

Now we can insert it into a `vector`:

```
vector<nameGrades> vng;
vng.push_back(NG);
```

Finally, we can insert it into the map:

```
TheBook tb;
tb[12345017] = vng;
```

Comment: Also, for a good stl reference have a look at: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Now, is printing it a whole other beast? Would it be similar to printing a nested array, except a lot more complicated? I've done some research on the iterators and such associated with Maps, but combining it with the vectors and structs might make it more challenging.

@TonyWilk, yup! I've checked that out a few times. It definitely put me on the right starting foot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After fixing your code (`#include <string>`) and the `TheBook` typedef (put a space between `>>`), you can access it like this:

```
TheBook aBook;
aBook[1]     // Access map<int, THIS> > where int==1
[2]          // Access vector<NameGrades>[THIS] where THIS==2
.v[3]        // Access NameGrades.v[3]
.grade = 5;
```

If you want to add something to a book, do it like this:

```
GradeCategories a,b,c,d;
NameGrades v1,v2;

v1.v.push_back(a); v1.v.push_back(b);
v2.v.push_back(c); v2.v.push_back(d);

vector<NameGrades> outerVector;
outerVector.push_back(v1); outerVector.push_back(v2);

TheBook aBook;
aBook[1] = outerVector;
```

Comment: The double angle brackets `>>` are valid C++ 11

Comment: @NicolaMusatti the topic doesn't have a `C++11` tag.

Comment: Won't that throw an exception unless you've initialized the vector?

Comment: @TonyWilk it will. Added the initialization code. Thought about it after adding the answer, and was already editing. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: C++ 11 *is* C++ and has been for over two years.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti There's a tag `C++11` for tagging questions in which the author wants answers valid in `C++11`. You should know that with 9k+ reputation. That's why it was separated from the normal `C++` tag anyhow. Moreover - even in C++11 the space between the brackets __will__ be valid.

Comment: I know that, but the OP appears to be a beginner so he/she might not be aware of the distinction and he/she is using a modern compiler, so suggesting a correction for a problem that likely is not there may be slightly confusing.

Comment: @PawełStawarz, so I'm walking through your example in my head...
In the second part, you're creating multiple structs (a,b,c,d and v1,v2 with unpopulated data), correct? So the first part: `v1.v.push_back(a);` would be adding `a` to the `v` vector in NameGrades? Then, `vector<NameGrades> outerVector; outerVector.push_back(v1);` is pushing that vector (`v1`) into the vector of NameGrades? Finally, `aBook[1] = outerVector;` is associating the KEY of 1 with the `outerVector`, correct? I believe that's what I'm interpreting it as. **EDIT:** used wrong characters for coding.

Comment: @CozmoNaught yes, you're correct :) The values withing `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are not initialized to save space in the example.